# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at Object.readSync

Tags: android, gradle, build, react-native

when i enter to my react native application from android device the app crash and it's throw the next error:

image of the error：

[image]

thanks for helping
I try to delete node modules and reinstall and delete the app and build again and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to be due to metro bundler and source maps requested by the browser (Chrome in my case), I've listed the steps below in solving this.

**Note:**
The patch script mentioned below is only related to `metro@0.64.0`. If you have another version, you can try modifying the script or searching through GitHub issues for [metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues) for something related to your version.

1. Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) by running `yarn add patch-package`.
2. Next, edit your `package.json` file and add this line within `scripts`:

```
"postinstall": "patch-package"
```

3. Now `mkdir patches` in your project's root directory (if you don't have one already).
4. Add the script below into `patches/metro+0.64.0.patch`:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js b/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js
index 5f32fc5..2b80fda 100644
--- a/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js
+++ b/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js
@@ -346,7 +346,7 @@ class UnableToResolveError extends Error {
     try {
       file = fs.readFileSync(this.originModulePath, "utf8");
     } catch (error) {
-      if (error.code === "ENOENT") {
+      if (error.code === "ENOENT" || error.code === 'EISDIR') {
         // We're probably dealing with a virtualised file system where
         // `this.originModulePath` doesn't actually exist on disk.
         // We can't show a code frame, but there's no need to let this I/O
```

5. Run `yarn postinstall` and it should patch `metro@0.64.0`.
6. In Chrome dev tools, uncheck:

   - Enable JavaScript source maps
   - Enable CSS source maps
7. Run `react-native start` and you should be good to go.

Reference: GitHub => react-native-fs => [Issue 991](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/991)