# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read - app crash on launch

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at Object.readSync (fs.js:564:3)
at Object.readSync (C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:147:28)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:349:20)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:386:19)
at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:347:17)
at new UnableToResolveError (C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:333:35)
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
at C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:317:42
at C:\Users\LiavOz\isradate1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1471:14
```

when I open my app the app crash immediately and throw the arror above
can someone help me to fix that?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at Object.readSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68087660/error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-at-object-readsync)

Comment: I think this is not the reason why your app crashes. I see the same errors in many working apps built with React Native 0.63 or 0.64, and my apps seems to work fine. It's annoying but most probably not the reason why your app is crashing